# Объединить два условия на php

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть 2 условия на php. Нужно их объединить. Подскажите как правильно?

```
if($arItem['ELEMENT_ID'] == $_POST["item_id"] && $arItem['COLOR'] && $arItem['COLOR'] == $_POST["FIELD_COLOR"])
    {
        $basket_num = $key;
        break;
    }

if($arItem['ELEMENT_ID'] == $_POST["item_id"] && $arItem['SIZE'] && $arItem['SIZE'] == $_POST["FIELD_SIZE"])
        {
            $basket_num = $key;
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Первое условие в скобки, второе в скобки, между ними ||    Но будет нечитаемо

Answer (score 0):

```
if($arItem['ELEMENT_ID'] == $_POST["item_id"] && $arItem['COLOR'] && $arItem['COLOR'] == $_POST["FIELD_COLOR"] OR arItem['ELEMENT_ID'] == $_POST["item_id"] && $arItem['SIZE'] && $arItem['SIZE'] == $_POST["FIELD_SIZE"])
{
    $basket_num = $key;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
if (
     $arItem['ELEMENT_ID'] == $_POST['item_id'] &&
     ( ($arItem['COLOR'] && $arItem['COLOR'] == $_POST['FIELD_COLOR']) ||
       ($arItem['SIZE']  && $arItem['SIZE']  == $_POST['FIELD_SIZE']) )
   ) {
    $basket_num = $key;
    break;
}
```

Хотя я бы не полагался на "==" и автоматическое приведение типов, а воспользовался явным приведением типов и "===". И подумал бы над использованием `$_POST` или `$_GET` напрямую и возможностью вместо них использовать `$_REQUEST` - это может дать больше гибкости в формировании запроса без необходимости корректировки кода, который этот запрос обрабатывает.

**Update**

Как верно заметил в комментариях @And, приведенному коду не хватает проверки и фильтрации входных данных. Но, поскольку этот код явно взят откуда-то из середины (судя по наличию `break`) алгоритма, я не посчитал нужным включать фильтрацию в код. Потому что делать это стоит **до** первого использования фильтруемых данных и обладая всей полнотой информации о допустимых значениях, а не "тут играем, тут не играем, тут - рыбу заворачиваем".

Comment: Нужно использовать `filter_input`, а не какие-то там, `$_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST`.

Comment: Ну, использование `filter_input()` или ее неиспользование зависит от личных предпочтений программиста к методам обработки _уже полученных_ данных. Я же говорю об _источнике_ данных. И, кстати, в filter_input() этот источник также выбирается параметром _int $type_. IMHO.

Comment: Он выбирается исключительно константой, а фильтруется внутрях, в вашем случае ничего не фильтруется и будут сыпаться нотисы и образовываться дырки и тормоза.

Comment: @And, если на то пошло, то я не пишу код. Я адаптирую кусок чужого кода под выставленное условие. Я обращаю внимание автора кода на возможные альтернативы, а не переписываю за него "сочинение на заданную тему". Потому что это будет для него более понятно. Так что "случай" - **не мой**. И да, я предпочитаю другие методы фильтрации "сырых" данных, отличные от использования filter_input(). И - не поверите! - нотайсы в **моем** коде не сыпет, дырки и тормоза - не возникают. :)